# How can functions with derivatives always positive decrease?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose I have a function where the derivative if always positive. For example

$$f(x) = x $$

Then

$$f'(x) = 1$$

If I interpret $f'(x)$ as rate of change and it's always positive, how can $f(x)$ ever decrease?

What I mean by decrease is this. Suppose I'm at 0. If I move to 1 the function increases. If I move to -1 the function decreases. With a derivative that's always positive why the asymetry?

Comment: It can't. $f$ is an increasing function.

Comment: $f$ is increasing! put some values and check yourself!

Comment: Maybe I'm not saying this right. Suppose I'm at 0. If I move to 1 the function increases. If I move to -1 the function decreases. With  a derivative that's always positive why the asymetry?

Comment: @badmax Suppose that this intuition of yours held true - how would we ever have increasing functions? Things can't increase "both ways". "Increasing" is defined in terms of some interval, from one end to the other.

Comment: That's why I'm having trouble with it. Is it true then that derivatives are defined with respect to a change in the positive direction and that for the negative direction the change is the negative of the derivative?

Comment: It's a convention that numbers increase from left to right in a number line. Thus, starting at $-1$ and travelling up to $0$, the function you proposed is increasing, as $f(-1) = -1 < 0 = f(0)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your comment, it seems you're confused about the meaning of "increasing". When we say $f$ is increasing, what we mean is that $f(x)$ increases *as $x$ increases*; i.e. as we "move to the right".

If you want a function to increase no matter which direction you move in, you're in a lot of trouble: if you can increase $f(x)$ by moving to the right over some interval, then moving to the left over the same interval must necessarily decrease $f(x)$!

Comment: This looks like a good intuitive explanation to me of what the OP is tripped up on.

Comment: So as we move to the left the change is just the negative of the derivative?

Comment: @badmax: yes, the rate of change of $f(x)$ as $x$ moves to the left (i.e. decreases at unit speed) is $-f'(x).$